# Can I install libcurl.so.2 on centos 7?

Tags: linux, curl, centos, centos7

I have an application that require libcurl.so.2 to run.
But I find nothing about libcurl.so.2 on centos 7.
Anyone can help? Thank you!

The command returns:

```
error while loading shared libraries: "libcurl.so.2"
```

Comment: Plenty of `compat-` packages, none with "libcurl.so.2" http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ ......... But you can make a `compat-libcurl2` from curl-7.11 https://src.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/curl/curl-7.11.1.tar.bz2/c2af7c3364a1a8839516f74961b6bd11/curl-7.11.1.tar.bz2   .... or if 32bit from a Fedora 2 curl package.

Comment: It seems that `libcurl.so.2` pre-dates the last two decades... Is this the only lib your app requires? It might have more ancient dependencies.